# c++ std::map class with generic key

Tags: c++, generics, stl, stdmap

I have a family of classes, and each subclass needs a map but the keys will have different types, although they both will perform the exact same operations with the map. Also the value on both cases will be string.
So far I have code similar to the example below, my goal is to reuse code, by
having a generic key.
Without using any additional libraries besides STL

```
class A{
 public:
    /*
     * More code
     */
};


class subA1 : public A{
public:
    void insertValue(long id, std::string& value){
        if(_theMap.find(id) == _theMap.end())
        {
            _theMap[id] = value;
        }
    }

 private:
     std::map<long,std:string> _theMap;
};

class subA2 : public A{
public:
    void insertValue(std::string& id, std::string& value){
        if(_theMap.find(id) == _theMap.end())
        {
            _theMap[id] = value;
        }
    }
private:
     std::map<std::string,std:string> _theMap;

};
```

Comment: What do you mean _generic key_? Another template? A `std::variant`?

Comment: Besides having different map types, are there any other differences between subclasses?

Comment: balki: both subclasses perform very different operations, but the store and retrieval for data in the map is identical, and some other code in common

Comment: @ulitosCoder In that case, this solution should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40370038/463758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge `subA1` and `subA2` into a single template class, eg:

```
class A{
 public:
    /*
     * More code
     */
};

template <typename KeyType>
class subA : public A {
public:
    void insertValue(const KeyType &id, const std::string& value) {
        if(_theMap.find(id) == _theMap.end()) {
            _theMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, value));
        }
    }

 private:
     std::map<KeyType, std:string> _theMap;
};
```

You can then create typedefs as needed:

```
typedef subA<long> subA1;
typedef subA<std::string> subA2;
```

Or, if you need actual derived classes:

```
class subA1 : public subA<long>
{
    ...
 };

class subA2 : public subA<std::string>
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution, because I need class A to be abstract as I don't know which specific subclass instance I'm going to create until runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Simply make superclass A a template, move both _theMap and insertValue() to it, and use the correct template version in subclasses.

```
template <typename KeyT>
class A{
 public:
   void insertValue(KeyT id, std::string& value){
        if(_theMap.find(id) == _theMap.end())
        {
            _theMap[id] = value;
        }
    }

 private:
     std::map<KeyT, std:string> _theMap;
};

class subA1 : public A<long> {};

class subA2 : public A<std::string> {};
```

Comment: Depending on the actual relationship between `A`, `subA1`, and `subA2`, it might make sense to instead merge `subA1` and `subA2` into a single template `subA` that performs the contains the `map` and derives from non-template `A`.

Comment: He said in a comment that "both subclasses perform very different operations, but the store and retrieval for data in the map is identical".

Answer (score 0):

How about writing another small base class, say `C<T>` which is a `template typename T` and just includes a `map<T, string>` and your `insert` function. Then each new subclass of A will also be a subclass of `C` as well. So your `subA1` will be `public A, public C<long>` etc.